# Keep responsive inline-blocks positioned with responsive text word wrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have two inline blocks (image then content) that I want to position horizontally like this:

[image]

Though when the container gets smaller the image and content blocks no longer stay inline. I want the container to constantly increase in height to handle the wrapping of the content text like this:

[image]

If the container reaches a limit, the elements will shift and center but at all times trying not create as little whitespace on the sides as possible like this:

[image]

I have some HTML that almost works: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tXke7/)

```
<div style="margin:20px; height:auto; box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #999999;   border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#dddddd; padding:4px; background-color:white; " >
        <div style="width:100%;" >
            <div style="display:inline-block; padding-top:4px; height:100px; width:100px;">
                <img src='http://placekitten.com/100/100'>
            </div>  
            <div style="display:inline-block;  vertical-align:top; padding-top:4px; min-width:70%; max-width:70%;">
                <h2 style=" font-size:12px;">About</h2>
                <p style="font-size:10px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle shows that you're giving `max-width` of 70% to the inner div.

Comment: Removing the max-width only makes the problem worse :)

Comment: I guess I can't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: Just to create the effect shown in the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my fiddle. I guess that is what you're after:

http://jsfiddle.net/tXke7/3/

```
.wrap {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.wrap img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.wrap p {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
    .wrap img {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .wrap p {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: only if you want to work with percentages. but then it would affect the image size, which would shrink on smaller resolutions and enlarge on higher resolutions. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `text-align: center` to the outer block.  Inner divs will inherit this, so you should also add `text-align: left` to the text block.

http://jsfiddle.net/tXke7/1/

Comment: If you increase the window size the container looses positioning

Comment: What do you mean by that? Try removing the min-width as well.